# item pipeline executes for only last url in start_requests

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I have some JSON file with "links" attribute in it. Here is a sample of these files :

```
{
"links": [
  "https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/1343-metropol-ankara",
  "https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/1347-bianco-boutique"
],
"names": [
  "Metropol Ankara hotel",
  "Bianco Boutique hotel",
  "Asal Ankara hotel",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I need to read all of these files and for every link, scrape the page and run the pipeline. Some files have only on link, Item pipeline runs for that files correctly, but for the files with more than one link, Item pipeline only runs for the last link in "links" attribute of JSON file. 
This is my spider code so far :

```
class HotelInfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def start_requests(self):
        files = [f for f in listdir('lastsecond/hotels/') if isfile(join('lastsecond/hotels/', f))]


    for file in files:
        with open('lastsecond/hotels/' + file, 'r') as hotel_info:
            hotel = json.load(hotel_info)
            for link in hotel["links"]:
                yield scrapy.Request(link, meta={'id': file})
    name = 'hotel_info'
    allowed_domains = ['lastsecond.ir']
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'lastsecond.pipelines.hotelFile': 400
        }
    }
    def parse(self, response):
        tour = ItemLoader(item=tourItem(), response=response)
        tour.add_css('name', '.tours-list h5 a::text')
        tour.add_css('nights', '.tours-list ul.mx-1 li:last-child label::text')
        tour.add_value('found_date', str(datetime.now()))
        tour.add_value('id', response.meta['id'])
        yield tour.load_item()
```

And this is my pipeline code:

```
class hotelFile(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        with open('lastsecond/results/' + item['id'][0], 'w') as result:
            json.dump(dict(item), result)
        return item
```

Also i have another problem too, in the output file, i only see the item fields that i assigned with `add_value` . Any field that i assigned with `add_css` does not exist in the outpu file. 
Those were my two problems in this code.

Comment: Please show complete code and correct its formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('lastsecond/results/' + item['id'][0], 'w') as result:
    json.dump(dict(item), result)
```

You're re-opening the file for writing every time, which causes you to overwrite its contents.
You should either open the file for appending, or only open it once.

As for your second problem, your code looks like it should work.
Make sure the css selectors actually match what you're trying to extract (the second one in particular looks super-specific).